# React Native style, useref and easing transition

Tags: react-native

I am learning react native and I am building an app for the first time.
I am trying to build an app that brings random quotes.
My app displays a random quote when the page loads and when I click the refresh button, it randomly gives another quote.
Whenever the quotes change, I want to make each quote `color` change as well.
But my below code does not work.
I receive an error as `cannot set properties of undefined(setting 'color')`

I believe the error is because I used `quoteRef.current.style.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]` in my useEffect hook

How can I do this so that it can work?

Also, how can give a slide-down effect to the text when clicked. I checked the documentation and watched a lot of videos however could not be successful on that as well.

My app looks like what I attached right now:

[image: app-display]

My code is below:

```
app.js

import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, SafeAreaView, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';


export default function App() {
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([]);
  const quoteRef = useRef();
  let colors = ["#ffff00", "#90ee90","#ffa500", "#ff68ff", "#a9a9e7"]

  const getQuotes = () => fetch('https://quotable.io/quotes?page=1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>
          {
            let randomQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.results.length);
            setQuotes(data.results[randomQuote])
          }
          );

  useEffect(() => {
    getQuotes()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    quoteRef.current.style.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
  }, [quotes])

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
      {/* {quotes.map(quote => <Text key={quote._id}>{quote.content}</Text>)} */}
        <Text ref={quoteRef}>{quotes.content}</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={getQuotes}
        title="Refresh"
        color="#841584"
        accessibilityLabel="Refresh"
      />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 35 : 0,
  },
});
```

Comment: "Also how can give a slide-down effect to the text when clicked" -- best to ask only a single question per question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is it happened because the `quoteRef` is initially empty

```js
const quoteRef = useRef();
```

and you tried to access it in this line

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    quoteRef.current.style.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
  }, [quotes])
```

instead, what you can do is to create a state for the color OR make `quotes` to be an Object of `{text: string, color: string}`, so you can hold both the quote text and color in `quotes`. I'll show you example for both cases.

1. add state for color

```js
 const [quoteColor, setQuoteColor] = useState("");

 useEffect(() => {
    setQuoteColor(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)])
  }, [quotes])
```

2. set `quotes` as an Object

```js
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState({text: "", color:""});
  const getQuotes = () => fetch('https://quotable.io/quotes?page=1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>
          {
            let randomQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * 
              data.results.length);
            const randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
              colors.length)]
            setQuotes({text: data.results[randomQuote], color: randomColor})
          }
          );
```

Comment: that makes sence. i tried those but did not work :( maybe i m missing something. but thank you so much for your answer. i really appreciate it

Comment: have you passed the `color` as a `style` to the `Text` component? I just realised I forgot to write it in the answer

Comment: ohh thank you, i also forgot. should i write like this ? style = {color: quoteColor }

Comment: it should be `style={{color: quoteColor}}`

Comment: it worked , thank youuuuu co much :)

Comment: @Ayse8888 no worries. accept this as answer if you don't mind :)

Comment: sure :) @jted95